# SQL: Add All option to MS Access Query and Combobox

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, combobox

I have this SQL statement to query the options in the combobox:

```
SELECT [Car].Type FROM [Car] GROUP BY [Car].Type
```

My attempt to modify the SQL statement to get an all option to display every item from the .Type options, yet this does not quite work. I have been studying the elements of the code and need a little assistance.

```
SELECT [Car].Type FROM [Car] GROUP BY [Car].Type UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 0, "**ALL**" FROM [Car];
```

What might be wrong the with statement?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT CStr([car].type) 
FROM   car 
GROUP  BY [car].type 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 1 CStr(0) 
FROM   car 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 1 'All' 
FROM   car;`

Comment: I tried it but Access gives me the error: Undefined function convert in the expression.

Comment: try the edited code above and let me know..basically you need to convert car.type and 0 to string because your ALL is a string. In UNION ALL all your variables needs to be the same data type.

Comment: Yes this works. Yet it does not return every item in the table to view again.

Comment: I also get a '0' th item with the ALL item... any suggestion?

Comment: based on your main query you wanted to get 0 as part of your result. if you dont want 0 just remove the  ' SELECT TOP 1 CStr(0) 
FROM   car '

Comment: Maybe I should set a VBA statement to respond to if the ALL option is chosen or do you think SQL can do it?

Comment: you need to set a VBA statement to respond to the ALL option. SQL cant do it. if the selection is = ALL then car.type

Comment: I think I can do the VBA with the ALL, the 0 th item should be the blanks or nulls in the field. What SQL might I use to Id, just is null?

Comment: I got the code figured out far enough. I should be able to do more on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I might be inclined to write the expression like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CStr(car.type) as type
FROM  car 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT "All"
FROM car;
```

If you have a handy table with just one row, then use that for the second part, rather than `car`.

Comment: I figure the distinct works around the grouping into one item of each?

Comment: @safron6 . . . They should do the same thing (using `group by` or `distinct`).  The latter just seems more succinct for this purpose.